# Rear seat for kids electric bike above battery

Tags: electric-bike, child-seat

I have a bicycle as in the picture. Are there any child seats that can be fixed in the rear of this bicycle?

ANy suggestion is appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Ask the manufacturer or otherwise determine if that rack is ISO 11243 compliant. If it is, there are kid seats that'll work on it.

Comment: @whatsisname Thanks for your reply.  I can see its written in the cycle it is ISO 11243 compliant.

Comment: Then double check the weight capacity of the rack is rated for at least the weight of **combined** the battery and the kid seat + kid, then you're good to go.

Comment: @whatsisname Wait capacity seems fine it is mentioned as 25kg.

Comment: @Ajith okay - strap a 15~20 kg sack of potatoes on your carrier and go for a ride.  See how it feels.

Comment: @Ajith that weight limit may have to take into account the weight of the battery, as well as the seat + child. That means only a baby would fit within the limit.

Comment: It's a shame that frame can't handle a seat tube mounted bike seat by the look of things. That worked well on a bike with the battery behind the seat tube

Comment: I would be extremely dubious of heavily loading the style or rack pictured where it appears to be an adjustable size with a separate tab connected by bolts down near the dropout.  They tend to fail where those extra holes are drilled.

Answer (score 3):

In the Netherlands, where most parents cycle with their kids, kids seats are now routinely attached to the seatpost or the part of the frame where the seat post drops into.

The kid will be above the rack but much of the weight will be on the middle of the frame.
There is no contact between the seat and the rack with battery. Many e-bikes are sold with both front and rear kid seats.

I did not find any 'non commercial' pictures so far, but if you google -bobike rear kid seat-  you will find several or many of that brand (other brands are also likely to have them, but I do not know their names, I am not connected to the brand in any way, I just see them used often.)

Do not worry about the weight of the child, many Dutch ride with adults on the rear rack, with no problems. (The racks may not like it, the weight spread over the bike works.) Just keep an eye on how you handle the bike with the weight there.
And do not forget the child when you get on or off when you are used to a diamond frame, [see this video fragment.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aESqrP3hfi8&t=150s)

Comment: Bobike certainly have some interesting products. Their bigger seats with higher weight limits are about the only ones available in the UK for older children. A reasonably heavy rider with any luggage mounted forwards shouldn't have trouble. The low, heavy motor of an e-bike will help

Comment: If the video link does not work for you, it is at 2:30 in the vid. (Youtube insist on my registering on all different browsers and if you do not, the direct link does not work.)

Answer (score 2):

I would not install a child seat over the battery on a bike like that - it is just too much rear weight, and its also high-up weight which will mess up the bike's feel.

Instead I'd personally choose a mid-mount seat, that goes between the stem and saddle.  For example:

[image]  
 This style sites the child inside the rider's arms so they can see what's coming up, rather than staring at your back.  Some have a padded panel in front of the child for sleeping on, and as protection.  Plus the child can communicate with the rider better.

Your bike lacks a top-tube, but this style of seat goes on its own support bar, and you can fit one of these to each bike, while just moving the seat between bikes.

You can also get some that sit right out the front in front of the bars, where your basket is, but these hamper the steering in the same way the rear seat does.

---

Other options include a trailer,
[image]

Or a tag-a-long style half bike though these would be for larger children:

[image]

Comment: You cover a decent range of options for various sizes of child (i.e. +1), but you can be unlucky - mine is too tall for a trailer, far too big for a front seat (which my knees couldn't handle anyway), but not confident enough for a tag-a-long

Comment: Front seats on the handle bars require quite a bit of space and only thin people can use them on many standard bikes. Yes, you can get special bikes for them but OP seems to have a bike.